# Adding a file to a bucket on Amazon S3 using C#

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3

How can I save a bitmap object as an image to Amazon S3?

I've got everything setup but my limited C sharp is stopping me from getting this done.

```
// I have a bitmap iamge
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(width, height);

// Rather than this
image.save(file_path);

// I'd like to use S3
S3 test = new S3();
test.WritingAnObject("images", "testing2.png", image);

// Here is the relevant part of write to S3 function
PutObjectRequest titledRequest = new PutObjectRequest();
titledRequest.WithMetaData("title", "the title")
             .WithContentBody("this object has a title")
             .WithBucketName(bucketName)
             .WithKey(keyName);
```

As you can see the S3 function can only take in a string and save it as the body of the file.

How can I write this in such a way that it will allow me pass in a bitmap object and save it as an image? Maybe as a stream? Or as a byte array?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Ummm... save your image to a file, convert the file to a hex string and pass that string? I know nothing about s3 but I think this can help.

Comment: I don't want the overhead of saving the image to a file first. I am sure it can be done whilst the image is still in memory.

Comment: Then save it to a memory stream.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You would use `WithInputStream` or `WithFilePath`. For example on saving a new image to S3:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using(var yourBitmap = new Bitmap())
    {
        //Do whatever with bitmap here.
        yourBitmap.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg); //Save it as a JPEG to memory stream. Change the ImageFormat if you want to save it as something else, such as PNG.
        PutObjectRequest titledRequest = new PutObjectRequest();
        titledRequest.WithMetaData("title", "the title")
            .WithInputStream(memoryStream) //Add file here.
            .WithBucketName(bucketName)
            .WithKey(keyName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok this makes sense, how would I convert a Bitmap object to a memory stream? Apologies if this a simple question but I am a newbie when it comes to c#.

Comment: @Abs: I updated the code sample to include an example of saving a Bitmap to a MemoryStream.

Comment: It worked. But I had to put the call to `.WithInputStream(memoryStream)` after the `WithKey(keyName)`. I now just have to solve a can not access a closed stream when I attempt to do this: `using (S3Response responseWithMetadata = client.PutObject(titledRequest))` - any ideas?

Comment: @vcsjones - its on the line I pasted in the above comment. Its not your code, its just something I thought I could get the response.

Comment: @Abs: Make sure you are doing that inside of the memoryStream using block so that the MemoryStream isn't closed before it tries to upload to S3.

Comment: @vcsjones - it is within the using block. See full function here: http://pastebin.com/5dTiZ8Di - I appreciate your continued help! Line 20 is the culprit.

Comment: @Abs: Your `client.PutObject(titledRequest);` call should be inside the using statement (between line 16 and 17).

Comment: @vcsjones - Fantastic! Thank you for your help. It is much appreciated from a c# newbie like me.

Answer (score 2):

Set the InputStream property of your request object:

```
titledRequest.InputStream = image;
```